# C++ How to put an integer into an character array

Tags: c++, arrays, type-conversion

I'm going mad trying to figure this out but nothing I try is working. Please help me out here.

```
char ch[5];
int in = 15;
ch[2] = in; // It has to be on a specefic place in that array
cout << ch[2]; // Prints '*'
```

I know i can do something like `ch[2] = in+48;` but that will only work with numbers smaller than 10.

Comment: `int` is bigger than `char`. Are you trying to truncate the `int` value to the size of a `char`, or split the `int` up into multiple `char`'s?

Comment: You can't. What that does is *type-cast* the integer to a `char`, which basically chops off the high bits and only leaves the eight low bits which happens to be the same value as the ASCII code for `'*'`.

Comment: What are you expecting `cout` to print?  `15`?

Answer (score 1):

When `cout` receives a `char`, it interprets it as a character (according to the execution character set) rather than just an integer value. If you want to print the integer value, you'll need to cast it to some other integer type:

```
cout << static_cast<int>(ch[2]);
```

Note that you will almost certainly not be able to store all the values of an `int` in a `char`. If your `char` is 8 bits (which it probably is), then `255` is the maximum value you can store in it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Interesting.. what exactly happened here?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I prefer the cast because it expresses intention.

Comment: @Digital_Reality: Unary `+` results in integral promotion.

Comment: @sftrabbit: Me too ;)